# Angular ng-repeat filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of FAQs that I receive from an ajax call as well as an separate array of FAQ Categories and I'm trying to do something where when you click on the category of that FAQ, only those that have a matching categoryId are shown. I have been trying A LOT of different things including ng-show but now my efforts are focused on trying to get |filter: working. Any help would be greatly appreciated...Here is the code:

```
   <div data-ng-controller="FAQController as dashboard" id="ctrler">

      <div ng-repeat="cat in dashboard.categories" class="col-md-2">
                <a data-ng-click="dashboard.filterForAnimation(cat)" href="#">
                    <div class="panel category-panel" data-fill-color="" data-context="">
                        <div class="panel-body background-6">
                            <span hidden class="cat-question-id" value="{{cat.id}}"></span>
                            <h4 class="question-category category-1">{{cat.name}}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
    <!-- visbile FAQs -------------------->
        <div class="col-md-4 FAQ fades" data-ng-repeat="x in dashboard.visibleFaqs track by x.id | filter:dashboard.filter">
            <div class="panel-body background-6 bg-grd-dark" data-fill-color="true">
                <h4 class="headline question">{{x.question}} </h4>
                <p class="answer">{{x.answer}}</p>
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-1x mr-1x" href="/FAQs/{{x.id}}/edit">Edit</a>
                <button type="button" data-ng-click="dashboard.delete(FAQ)" class="btn btn-danger mb-1x mr-1x" data="{{x.id}}">Delete</button>
            </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
       (function () {
        "use strict";
        angular.module(APPNAME)
            .controller("FAQController", FAQController);

        FAQController.$inject = ['$scope', '$baseController', '$faqService'];

        function FAQController($scope, $baseController, $faqService) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.headingInfo = "FAQs"
            vm.faqItems = null;               
            vm.categories = null;
            vm.visibleFaqs = null;
            vm.selectedCategoryId = null;

            vm.$faqService = $faqService;
            vm.$scope = $scope;

            vm.receiveFAQItems = _receiveFAQItems;
            vm.onError = _onError;
            vm.delete = _delete;
            vm.deleteSuccess = _deleteSuccess;
            vm.getItemSuccess = _getItemSuccess;
            vm.filterForAnimation = _filterForAnimation;
            vm.filter = _filter;


            $baseController.merge(vm, $baseController);

            vm.notify = vm.$faqService.getNotifier($scope);

            render();

            function render() {
                vm.$faqService.getCategories(vm.getItemSuccess, vm.onError);
                vm.$faqService.ajaxGetAll(vm.receiveFAQItems, vm.onError);
            }

            function _getItemSuccess(data) {
                vm.notify(function () {
                    vm.categories = data.items;
                });
            }

            function _receiveFAQItems(data) {
                vm.notify(function () {
                    console.log(data.items);
                    vm.faqItems = data.items;                        
                })
            }

            function _onError(jqXhr, error) {
                console.error("error");
            }

            function _delete(faqArray) {
                var index = vm.faqItems.indexOf(faqArray);
                vm.faqItems.splice(index, 1);
                var id = faqArray.id;
                vm.$faqService.ajaxDelete(id, vm.deleteSuccess, vm.onError)
            }

            function _deleteSuccess(faqArray) {
                console.log("delete successful");
            }

            function _filterForAnimation(item) {
                console.log("category clicked");
                vm.selectedCategoryId = item.id;
                for (var i = 0; i < vm.faqItems.length; i++) {
                    if (vm.faqItems[i].categoryId == vm.selectedCategoryId){                                                                
                        vm.filter(vm.faqItems[i].categoryId, vm.selectedCategoryId)
                    }
                }

            }

            function _filter(faq, categoryId) {
                if (faq == categoryId) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    })()
```

Comment: can you paste the code in which you bind your controller to the html ex: `ng-controller="someCtrl as cm"`?

Comment: @Haymaker87 I pasted the wrapper div, thanks for looking at my question!

Answer (score 0):

Same way than previous answer, but different approach :

Change your `_filter` function to :

```
function _filter(faq) {
    return faq.categoryId == vm.selectedCategoryId;
}
```

Your `vm.selectedCategoryId` in set dynamically by the `_filterForAnimation`, so it will works.

You can also use angular filter provider like this :

```
function _filter() {
    return function(items, categoryId) {
        return items.filter(function(item) {
            return item.id == categoryId;
        });
    }
```

Declare it

```
angular.module(APP_NAME)
//...
.filter('categoryFilter', _filter);
```

And in your markup :

```
data-ng-repeat="x in dashboard.visibleFaqs track by x.id | categoryFilter:dashboard.selectedCategoryId"
```

---